# etckeeper doesn't checkout files automatically to /etc

Tags: linux, git, debian, push, git-push

Somewhy since I upgraded to Debian Jessie 8.3 and compiled GIT 2.6.0, etckeeper v1.15 doesn't doesn't checkout files automatically to /etc.

Reproducing steps:

1)  create file ddd.txt locally (Windows 7, git version 2.6.3.windows.1) with content:

```
root@local-debian8:/etc# 
printf "ddd\n" > ddd.txt
```

2) see with git

```
$ git status
On branch local_master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'local/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   ddd.txt
```

3) stage it

```
$ git add .
```

4) see as staged

```
$ git status
On branch local_master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'local/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   ddd.txt
```

5) commit it

```
$ git commit -m "ddd.txt"
[local_master 347862d] ddd.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 ddd.txt
```

6) Push it to NON-BARE repo on server (GIT repo, created by etckeeper)

```
$ git push local HEAD:master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 262 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@192.168.1.101/etc
   175d92e..347862d  HEAD -> master
```

On the server I see:
7) check is file exists on the server (is checked out? NO)

```
root@local-debian8:/etc# ls /etc/ddd.txt
ls: /etc/ddd.txt No such file or directory
```

8) see git status

```
root@local-debian8:/etc# git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    ddd.txt
```

9) see changes

```
root@local-debian8:/etc# git show
commit 347862d444f294c491330adc7e967659071d6b5e
Date:   Wed Feb 17 16:14:41 2016 +0100

    ddd.txt

diff --git a/ddd.txt b/ddd.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..1d60b70
--- /dev/null
+++ b/ddd.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+ddd
```

10) commit on server

```
root@local-debian8:/etc# git commit -m "ddd.txt"
```

Any idea what is the problem?
Is it an etckeeper bug, coming from incompatible git version or bad configuration?